# Responsive featured Image

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I created a new post and selected a featured image. For this, I created a class called `featured-image` (custom image size). The alignment is to the left, and I want it to be responsive. But for the following case, I don't have the result that I want. The image is not responsive.

Any help?

**functions.php** has the following code : -

```
<?php

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup' );  

    function setup() {  

        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

        add_image_size( 'featured-image', 590, 520, true );  

        }

 add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'custom_image_sizes_choose' );  

    function custom_image_sizes_choose( $sizes ) {  
        $custom_sizes = array(  
            'featured-image' => 'alignleft'  
        );  
        return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );  
    }  

?>
```

**category-id.php** has the following code : -

```
<div class="column two-third">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-image', array('class' => 'alignleft'));?>                                 
</div>
```

in the **post**:
ex:

```
<a href="http://www.domainname/testssss/attachment/2222" rel="attachment wp-att-246">
   <img src="http://www.domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/2222-590x520.png" alt="2222" class="alignleft size-featured-image wp-image-246" />
</a>
```

**style.css** has the following css rules :-

```
img.alignleft
{
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
    img.alignleft
    {
      max-width: 100%;
      display:block;
      height:auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, **I** is always capitalised in English when it is not part of another word. Also please pay special attention to your tagging, it's how people find your question so it's in your best interests to do it well! [tag:image] is not enough, always use the tag of the language you are using as well.

Comment: Thanks for the edit / comments.

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me. For example, what do you mean by "I want to be responsive"? Also, you start off talking about a class named `responsive` but this isn't reflected in the code (and why did you post the CSS definitions for "alignLeft"?). -- Could you rephrase what you're trying to do? And maybe give an example of the actual and the desired output.

Comment: @Niko ,now the question is more clearly?

Comment: Your problem is that the CSS is not being applied to the image (even though it is in your .css file and the image has been assigned the right class), did I understand that correctly?

Comment: The image assigned the left class, not the right. Look at the example below: http://cssdeck.com/labs/sokxxdar.

Comment: What about the CSS of `size-featured-image` ?

Comment: I meant "right" in the sense of "correct". However, I still don't get what you mean by "I want it to be responsive" - do you want the image to be clickable? Could you build up a full example?

Comment: After many tests i found the solution. The image is now responsive and "re-size" .img.size-full { max-width: 100%; display:block; height: auto !important;}